# Directory structure for multiple distributed python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-wheel

This question unfortunately requires a little bit of setup so bear with me:

Suppose my startup, travel-is-cool, has three pieces of code

- A python packages with information about bicycles
- A python package with information about the weather
- A C++ library completely that does something but isn't important for the question.

All python code is written with python3.8.10, though it might move to python3.10 in the future.

The folder structure at this startup looks like the following:

```
travel-is-cool/ # git root
---- cpp/
---- python/
-------- setup.py
-------- src/
------------ bicycle/
---------------- __init__.py
---------------- bicycle.py 
---------------- # Plenty of additional files and folders, this is a large project!
------------ weather/
---------------- __init__.py
---------------- weather.py
---------------- # Plenty of additional files and folders, this is a large project!
```

I've looked over the code and decided I want to enable developers to use `pip install travel-is-cool-bicycle` and `pip install travel-is-cool-weather` on their local machines, as these packages are totally separate from one another! I'd also like to build wheels for them. I can't find any best practices with how to do this at all, however.

Is it possible for me to maintain the current structure, and have two `setuptools.setup` calls in my current setup.py? (Doesn't look like it)

Must I maintain a structure similar to the following:

- python/src/bicycle/setup.py
- python/src/bicycle/bicycle/code-goes-here

The repeated directory name in this solution seems to simply add clutter, but is a viable option in the worst case.

Is there some pyproject.toml trickery I need to be using? Where should I put that?

This question is mostly related to the correct file structure I need to maintain, and maybe partially related to the contents of a setup.py or associated file. I also require almost all python files to remain inside `python/src`  (one or two is OK as there are two packages).

Thanks for all the help!